# Google Charts - Hide series label too wide

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-visualization

With Google Apps Script I created a stacked bar chart. This is the result:
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DZ2ZtSu2A81OAMc9ds9A4y-bS0l_oftL/view?usp=sharing

I would like to hide the labels on the bars when they are too wide compared to the available space. Following the instructions I found at this address https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns I tried to use a custom function instead of "stringify" in the "annotationObj" object ( see the code) to create a label of zero length, but my function is not recognized when I try to create the chart (error message: Unknown function "getValueAt").

This is my code:

```
function CHARTS_002() { //
  var ABCarray = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','AA','AB','AC','AD','AE','AF','AG','AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN','AO','AP','AQ','AR','AS','AT','AU','AV','AW','AX','AY','AZ','BA','BB','BC','BD','BE','BF','BG','BH','BI','BJ','BK','BL','BM','BN','BO','BP','BQ','BR','BS','BT','BU','BV','BW','BX','BY','BZ','CA','CB','CC','CD','CE','CF','CG','CH','CI','CJ','CK','CL','CM','CN','CO','CP','CQ','CR','CS','CT','CU','CV','CW','CX','CY','CZ'];
  var ssId = '1KA2BnUsC-Lp64UhxjtN5Gtth2dOiHp3-pRwIQjAYOLI';
  var shName = 'TopGrossingFilms'; 
  var aScale = ["Poco d'accordo","Né d’accordo né in disaccordo","Abbastanza d'accordo","Totalmente d'accordo","Media"]; 
  var aRange = [['B',2],['N',12]];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(shName);
  var row = aRange[0][1];
  var column = ABCarray.indexOf(aRange[0][0]) + 1;
  var numRows = aRange[1][1] - aRange[0][1];
  var numColumns = ABCarray.indexOf(aRange[1][0]) - ABCarray.indexOf(aRange[0][0]) + 1;
  var sheetV = sheet.getRange(aRange[0][1], ABCarray.indexOf(aRange[0][0]) + 1, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
  var sheetT1D = sheetV[0];
  var aData = [];
  for (var r in sheetV) {
    aData.push(sheetV[r])
  }
  for (var r in aData) {
    for (var c in aData[r]) {
      if (!isNaN(aData[r][c])) {
        aData[r][c] = round(aData[r][c],2);
        if (aData[0][c] == 'Media') {
          aData[r][c] = 13;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var data = Charts.newDataTable();
  var annotationObj = { calc: "stringify", 
                       //calc: "getValueAt",
                       //calc: "function(data, row) { var ret = data[row][§col§]; if (ret < 7) {return '';} else {return JSON.stringify(ret)} }",
                       sourceColumn: -1,
                       type: "string",
                       role: "annotation"
                      }
  var aAnnotation = [];
  for (var r in aData) {
    if (r < 1) { continue; }
    if (r == 1) { 
      for (var c in aData[r]) {
        aAnnotation.push(c);
        if (isNaN(aData[r][c])) {
          data.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, aData[0][c]);
        } else {
          data.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, aData[0][c]);
          if (aScale.indexOf(aData[0][c]) != -1) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(annotationObj));
            var myCol = Number(c);
            if (aData[0][c] == 'Media') {
              myCol = Number(c) + 1;
            }
            myObj.sourceColumn = myCol;
            myObj.calc = myObj.calc.replace("§col§",myCol)
            aAnnotation.push(myObj);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    data.addRow(aData[r]);
  }
  var dataViewDefinition = Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns(aAnnotation);
  var aTicks = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
  var chartBuilder = Charts.newBarChart()
  .setDimensions(1200, 700)
  .setOption("hAxis", { ticks: aTicks})  
  .setOption('legend',{ position:'top', maxLines:3 })
  .setOption('chartArea',{ left:650 })
  .setOption('series',{
    6: {type:'line', color:'00FF00', lineWidth:3, visibleInLegend: false}
  })
  .setDataTable(data)
  .setDataViewDefinition(dataViewDefinition)
  .setOption('bar', { groupWidth: "80%" })
  .setStacked()
  .setColors(['#C10000','#F1C12A','#BFBFBF','#0070C1','#244062','00FF00']);

  var chart = chartBuilder.build();

  var chartImage = chart.getAs('image/png').copyBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(chartImage).setName('NewBarChart.png');
}

function getValueAt(column, dataTable, row) {
  var value = dataTable(row, column);
  var ret = '';
  if (value > 7) { ret = value.toString()}
  return ret;
}

function round(value, exp) {
  var funcName = 'round';
  if (typeof exp === 'undefined' || +exp === 0)
    return Math.round(value);

  value = +value;
  exp = +exp;

  if (isNaN(value) || !(typeof exp === 'number' && exp % 1 === 0))
  return NaN;

  // Shift
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  value = Math.round(+(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] + exp) : exp)));

  // Shift back
  value = value.toString().split('e');
  return +(value[0] + 'e' + (value[1] ? (+value[1] - exp) : -exp));
}
```

The chart that is produced can be seen in this public folder: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DZ2ZtSu2A81OAMc9ds9A4y-bS0l_oftL/view?usp=sharing

Does anyone know how to get the result I would like to get?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check if you are calling the function properly and passing the correct parameters, for what I see in your code, you do not call this function.

Comment: Thanks Kessy for the answer.

I added to the code the two attempts I had made to use an alternative function to "stringify" as comments. In both cases the error message says "Unknown function", so I believe that the parameters of the function are not even analyzed. It seems to me rather that custom functions are not recognized, although the example in the documentation would seem to say the opposite.

Comment: When calling the function getValueAt, you should do getValueAt(column, dataTable, row), because it's a function and needs these params.

Comment: I will also make this attempt, but "stringify" does not specify any parameters and it works. As I said the error message is "Unknown function" and not "Bad parameter" or something similar.

Comment: In your code when I run it shows me 2 errors and none of them are the ones you are talking about. Line 12 glABCarray that should be ABCarray. Line 21 round -> not defined.

In addition you could check the guide on stacked bar chart since in that there are no labels on the bars: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts

Comment: I corrected the code; now no more errors are reported.
I have already consulted the guide on the stacked bar, but unfortunately does not give information about my problem.
Thanks anyway.